# How can I sync a subset of Quote Line Items?

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, quote

Here's the basic rundown: I've got a checkbox on my Quote Line Item object, and when I sync the Quote I want to prevent some items from becoming Opportunity Line Items based on the value of that checkbox.

**So the question is:** how can I tap into the sync functionality to have it exclude certain records?

My colleagues and I have been working on this problem for a while and Google has turned up no information. Even our research on the syncing concept in general turns up nothing but the very bare-bones description of "how to sync a quote" and what it means when a quote is synced...

The only thing I've managed to find are people who want to keep data from custom fields in sync, and the only answer available seems to be [this app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IlfVEAS) which provides Custom Settings for mapping the fields.
I find it odd that nobody has even mentioned my use case, but the existence of that app tells me that it must be possible to communicate with the native sync process...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with my company's TAM (Salesforce representative), he has informed me that manipulating the native sync process is indeed **impossible**...

> "The synch process is not extensible, does not have an API, etc."

:(

He even sent me the unmanaged version of the package I had linked above, which turns out to be just a series of Custom Settings and Triggers. Quite disappointing...

The only way to hit my use case would be to either write an entirely custom sync process, or create a custom Line Item object to contain the items that I do not want synced (effectively meaning that those items will never exist as QuoteLineItems at all).